# Add sku as url for Programatically created Product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, url

I am creating Product Programtically. right now, i am giving product name as url for newly created Product, but i want to give product **sku as url key** .

**example** : **Original Product** :  name : **test** [url key = `test1` , sku = `1234` ]

**Programtcally created Product** : name : **test** [url key = `test1` , sku = `abcd` ]

Instead of `test1` i want to give new product's url-key as `abcd`, so that i can see in site with this url : `sitename.com/abcd.html`

```
public function saveProduct($type, $doSave = true, $originalProduct, $newImagePath) 
{
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
            
            $rand = rand(11, 999999999);
            $product->setTypeId($type)
            ->setSku('CDSB1_sku' . $rand);
            
            $product->setIsMassupdate(true)->setExcludeUrlRewrite(true);
            $product->setName($originalProduct->getName());
            $product->save();   
}
```

if that is not possible atleast i want to give some **random number** for "**Url Key**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set url key of product like this-

```
public function saveProduct($type, $doSave = true, $originalProduct, $newImagePath) 
{
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

            $rand = rand(11, 999999999);
            $product->setTypeId($type)
            ->setSku('CDSB1_sku' . $rand);
            $product->setUrlKey($rand); // change $rand with sku to set sku as url
            $product->setIsMassupdate(true)->setExcludeUrlRewrite(true);
            $product->setName($originalProduct->getName());
            $product->save();   
}
```

To redirect to the programmatically created product use this in your controller-

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
$this->_redirect($product->getUrl());
```

Comment: your solution worked fine, when i try to see product in site as `sitename.com/5678.html` , its giving 404 error, but when i edit the url key manually and save product and when i check in site, it works fine, is there any way to solve  this ?

Comment: try after reindexing

Comment: i will check it and inform you.....

Comment: sorry, one more thing, after `new product` is creating with `new url` , is there any way to redirect to that `new product url` ?

Comment: I have updated my answer